# how to send multiple object values as a single object to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on angularjs application. I'm iterating the response and displaying in a table, when user click on the table row information i'm passing the json value to the java script where i will process further and display information.

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in responseData">
<td>
    {{info.id}}</td>
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="showDetails(x.product1Data)">
    product1 Data</a>
</td>
<td style="width:15%;text-align: center;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="showDetails(x.product2Data)">
    product2 Data </a>
</td>
<td style="width:15%;text-align: center;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="showDetails(x.product3Data)">
    product3 Data</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="showDetails(..)">Show All Product Data </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

In the above html code, when user click on **Show All Product Data** i want to pass `x.product1Data,x.product2Data,x.product3Data` value to showDetails(..). Any inputs on how to pass all 3 objects in showDetails when user click on **Show All Product Data**

js code:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(productInfo){
//productInfo contains the product information
agularjs.forEach(productInfo,function(value,key){

}
}
```

Comment: Same way as you pass parameters into a normal funaction. `showDetails(x.product1Data,x.product2Data,x.product3Data)`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function called `showDetailSet()`, which takes an array as an argument. It could do something like (you will have to scope it obviously):

```
function showDetailSet(products) {
    products.forEach(p => showDetails(p))
}
```

Then you would call it like `ng-click="showDetailSet([x.product1Data, x.product2Data, x.product3Data])"`

Comment: +1 - I was looking your solution now, can i pass two arguments to showDetailSet(.) like showDetailSet(products,brand) where argument brand is String and products hold [x.product1Data, x.product2Data, x.product3Data] ..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call all `showDetail`s directly:

```
ng-click="showDetails(x.product1Data); showDetails(x.product2Data); showDetails(x.product3Data);">
```

You could also pass multiple arguments as you would to a normal function, but you would have to refactor `showDetails` for that.

Comment: I have to pass only one argument to showDetails which should have x.product1Data,x.product2Data,x.product3Data values. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Ok, then do it the first way instead, just put all `showDetails` calls in the last `ng-click`.

Comment: That's not working, i'm opening a new window with information when user click on showDetails, keeping all showDetails in ng-click is making to open window 3 times..

Comment: Sounds like it *is* working, but you want it to do something else. You should probably refactor `showDetails` (or make a completely new function) and figure out what you want to be displayed where when Show All Product Data is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your Json array is formatted, you may be able to push a concatenated variable such as

```
showDetails(x.product1Data.concat(x.product2Data.concat(x.product3Data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally parameters can be send by following code,

```
showDetails(x.product1Data,x.product2Data,product3Data)
```

dont know why this is not solving your problem, if it is not working then follow bellow,

Just pass `info` you will get all the `productData` in the `showDetails` function

```
 <tr ng-repeat="info in responseData">
    <td>
        {{info.id}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
           ng-click="showDetails(info.product1Data,$index)">
        product1 Data</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;text-align: center;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
           ng-click="showDetails(info.product2Data,$index)">
        product2 Data </a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;text-align: center;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
           ng-click="showDetails(info.product3Data,$index)">
        product3 Data</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
           ng-click="showDetails(info,-1)">Show All Product Data </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.showDetails = function(productInfo,index){
  if(index==-1)
   {
        // do your stuff for show all details
   }
   else{
      //productInfo contains the product information
       agularjs.forEach(productInfo,function(value,key){

       }
   }
}
```